# Verify on etherscan

Tags: etherscan, verify

Trying to verify contract 0x0568a87e64e65f4cc7898e08f0e57ffe2aa6241f, compiler 0.8.7 with source code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721,Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private currentTokenId;
    /// @dev Base token URI used as a prefix by tokenURI().
    string public baseTokenURI;
    uint256 maxNftAmount;
    constructor() ERC721("My Breathtaking Pixel Bois", "BOI") {
      baseTokenURI = "QmdjAPjtUTVGfPKumoUqMnsvDER28hcwB3jMAUgFaiGRQk/";
       maxNftAmount = 888;
    }
    
    function contractURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
       return "QmdzNse3GwYaDBxshS1jnBXAFqX3hepJtBBBQxEutn1Ave";
    }

    function mintFree()
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(currentTokenId.current() < maxNftAmount);
        require(balanceOf(address(msg.sender)) < 2);
        currentTokenId.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
        _safeMint(address(msg.sender), newItemId);
        return newItemId;
    }
  
    /// @dev Returns an URI for a given token ID
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseTokenURI;
  }

  /// @dev Sets the base token URI prefix.
  function setBaseTokenURI(string memory _baseTokenURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseTokenURI = _baseTokenURI;
  }

  function changeMaxMint(uint256 _maxAmount)public onlyOwner {
    maxNftAmount = _maxAmount;
  }

  function totalMinted() public view returns (uint) {
        return currentTokenId.current();
    }

}
```

Have tried flattening code and verifying it on ether scan but get error about wrong constructor ABI (516d646a41506a745554564766504b756d6f55714d6e7376444552323868637742336a4d4155674661694752516b2f) `Error! Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format`  , have tried to grab bigger constructor ABI from byte code but still get error  `Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI` (even tho the bytecode its looking for is the same as nft bytecode)

Other abi I used : `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`
Also dont know why but cant generate abi on https://abi.hashex.org/ - it just stays blank when trying to parse.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you deploy the contract? You should use the same settings (e.g: compiler optimization) to verify the contract.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy your contract and verify it myself and it worked..
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x09fCA943D2E8c9990f2a12617f58186De4ab4649#code
Did you use hardhat to verify it ?

Comment: no Im just trying to verify it old school through etherscan form, can you please specify what abi constructor did you use, or hardhat does it automaticly ?

Comment: once it is deployed, hardhat will do it automatically, no need to specify the abi